# Need help with Minecraft server admins

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have recently set up a Minecraft server. Only I have a problem with OPing people. Whenever I OP someone in the folder (ops.json) then load up the server (.exe) and enter Minecraft, it resets and the OP's wont stay. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Do not OP a player using The JSON File type because in a JSON File you cannot have any indentation and everything needs to be specific. So i reccomend OPing People Using The OP Command In The Console.

**Usage**

```
/op <username>
```

Comment: I hope this helped.

Comment: I have been trying to OP myself. It wont let me in game because I don't have permission.  So let me rephrase the question, how do I OP myself?

Comment: @Cheese server console

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience caused. If you want to OP Your In-Game character you should type the command : op <username> in the server's terminal rather than the In-Game chat region.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with 1.14+ when you go to the console of the terminal you can OPing people like so:

```
$ java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.14.3.jar nogui
...
...
[21:12:41] [Server thread/INFO]: sorcerjoe has made the advancement [Monster Hunter]
list
[21:12:44] [Server thread/INFO]: There are 2 of a max 20 players online: sorcerjoe, BrUhDuH
op BrUhDuH
```

In the above I'm running the server and then once it's started, waiting for users to join. Once they're in, I can check with the `list` command to see whose there. I can then run the `op` command with a given user's name to make them an op, aka, `op BrUhDuH`.

Doing it through the console of the server in a terminal will automatically add the user's to the corresponding `ops.json` file:

```
$ cat ops.json
[
  {
    "uuid": "db8ad9d7-be3b-40a2-a6ab-552a95af457b",
    "name": "RainbowRule",
    "level": 4,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  },
  {
    "uuid": "5f5e4602-b702-43e2-b414-82c6e31bc61b",
    "name": "sorcerjoe",
    "level": 4,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  },
  {
    "uuid": "a2f3109c-c41f-4ed9-9ca3-28e0aa0bcbf0",
    "name": "BrUhDuH",
    "level": 4,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  }
]
```

***NOTE:*** These are just made up UUIDs I'm showing here for demo purposes.

This is a simple JSON file, so you can of course edit this file by hand and then start the server up after. If you opt to do this bear in mind that you'll want to make sure that the file is properly formatted as JSON. I'd recommend using an online site to validate your JSON before copy/pasting it into your `ops.json` file.

#### References

- https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
- https://www.beastnode.com/portal/knowledgebase/118/Make-Yourself-An-OporOwnerorAdmin.html

Answer (score -2):

While you and whoever you're trying to op is in the game and on the server, type in /op [username] into the command prompt (the block box that is running in the background).